# Best way to avoid cables

Tags: ethernet, ieee-802.11

I organize sport events and to do that I need to create a network very time I go to a sport hall. Due to the sport type, I can not use 2.4 Ghz (this frequency causes issues with the scoring system), so I actually use cables and switch to connect a small server (with hosts the software that manages the sport event) and 10/15 clients placed in different points (one for each competition area). 
To do that I already have switches.

I'm looking for a solution to remove cables (which are very time expensive to be placed).

I cannot use pure 5Ghz wireless because computer which are actually used have just 2.4Ghz network adapter or, in some cases, they have just an ethernet port.

So, I'm looking for a way to place a central access point to bring wifi signal to every competition area (removing the necessity of long wires) and then place here a small switch, connected to a sort of wifi receiver, so I can still use cables to connect switch to the laptops on every competition area.

I thought about a central wireless router/AP with a repeater on each competition area (like that https://www.amazon.it/gp/product/B00KXULGJQ/ref=s9_simh_gw_g147_i2_r?pf_rd_m=A11IL2PNWYJU7H&pf_rd_s=&pf_rd_r=C2VBRXEBDTWAEK8EHY5F&pf_rd_t=36701&pf_rd_p=6127e987-ce6a-47ca-bd15-51701a16b93c&pf_rd_i=desktop), using the ethernet port plugged into the switch. But I think that on something like that I cannot disable wireless repeater, so I will get a lot of repeated wifi SSID with bad results (and a lot of electromagnetic pollution, which is bad for the scoring system)

Can you suggest me a better way to get this result?

Thank you very much

Andrea

Comment: The link you have is a consumer-grade product, which is off-topic here. Repeaters also halve, the speed since they cannot send and receive at the same time. Also, each WAP should serve not more than 20 or 30 hosts.

Comment: Thank you. Yes I know, I cannot find a business level product like that. The host number is not a problem, because I have just 2 or 3 hosts for each competition area, and maximum 15 competition areas to serve from the main AP. My question is: is that the right way or would I think about something different to avoid wires?

Comment: That is because repeaters mess things up. The business vendors do sell wireless bridges, which don't suffer from the same problem.

Comment: Thanks. Can you suggest me products (reliable but not too much expensive) with which I can place a central AP, which works only at 5GHz, which reach a range of 100/150m (also with external antenna if needed), and a set of bridges to do point-to-multipoint connections using the root AP as center?

Comment: Unfortunately, product or resource recommendations are explicitly off-topic here.